# Thymeleaf map syntax causes TemplateProcessingException

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to build a page with a grid of users and their permissions.  The project is a Spring MVC Boot + Thymeleaf project.  Versions:

1. Thymeleaf 3.0.3
2. Thymeleaf Layout Dialect 2.2.1
3. Spring Boot 1.5.2 
   (Note I had to override Spring Boot's Thymeleaf version because the
   Layout Dialect version was extremely out of date.)

Each user has an office and a number of roles.  RoleDescription, Office, and User are POJOs that contain a number of Strings.  I fill my data in the controller like this.

```
  @RequestMapping("/admin/users")
  public String userGrid(Model model) {
      MyWebServiceClient myClient = clientFactory.getClient();
      List<RoleDescription> roles = myClient.getRoleList();
      Map<String, Office> offices = myClient.getOfficeMap();
      List<User> users = myClient.getUserRoleGrid();
      model.addAttribute("offices", offices);
      model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
      model.addAttribute("users", users);
      return "usergrid";
  }
```

Then I display the data in my Thymeleaf templated page like this:

```
        <tbody th:each="user: ${users}" th:with="officeId=${user.officeId},office=${offices[officeId]}">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${user.fullName}">Fred User</td>
                <td th:text="${user.userId}">fred</td>
                <td th:text="${office.name} (${officeId})">Madison, Wisconsin (madison)</td>
                <th:block th:each="role: ${roles}">
                    <td th:text="${#lists.contains(user.roles, role)} ? 'yes'"></td>
                </th:block>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I've tried several variations of `offices[officeId]`, trying to retrieve the office name from the Map object.  The full form of the expression, without the `th:with` statement would look like `offices[user.officeId].name`.  I've dumped the office map to make sure it's not null, and it is full of data.

No matter what I do, I get some variation of:

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${office} (${officeId})"`

Just a comment: after working with Freemarker for a few years, which has become mature enough to give you almost preternaturally insightful error messages, this is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem here is the `th:with`.  It is in fact this statement: `<td th:text="${office.name} (${officeId})">Madison, Wisconsin (madison)</td>` which matches the error message.  I would recommend changing it to something like this to fix it / make it more readable:

```
<td>
    <span th:text="${office.name}" /> (<span th:text="${officeId}" />)
</td>
```

or to keep the original syntax

```
<td th:text="${office.name + ' (' + officeId + ')'}">Madison, Wisconsin (madison)</td>
```

Comment: To summarize: I shouldn't have jammed the parentheses in there.  I guess I had temporary parenthesis blindness.

Comment: I also just discovered that the "with" is useless in this context.  It sets the value of office to the first one in the list and doesn't update for each row.

Comment: @k-den `th:with` should work with `th:each` the way you want... I just verified with my own test cases.  Could you be overwriting the variable somewhere else?